# Crash on slow connection in Map box iOS SDK

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am using Map box iOS SDK 3.0.1 in my App and facing issues on slow network. It crashed very often.

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   std::runtime_error: Failed to load
>   [https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2,mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6/0/0/0.vector.pbf?access_token=pk.xxxx]:

and Xcode crash log is :

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x114edcff8 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax
    0x114edcffd <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x114edd000 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x114edd002 <+10>: jae    0x114edd00c               ; <+20>
    0x114edd004 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x114edd007 <+15>: jmp    0x114ed7bdd               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x114edd00c <+20>: retq   
    0x114edd00d <+21>: nop    
    0x114edd00e <+22>: nop    
    0x114edd00f <+23>: nop
```

Anyone faced any such issue with map box SDK ? Let me know how it can be prevented to the error can be bought ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give Mapbox iOS SDK v3.1.1 a try — there have been significant networking improvements made in the v3.1.x releases.

Comment: Got it confirmed from the support team , its been resolved in 3.1.1. Forgot to update the answer.

Comment: Still having the issue. :(